# System restarts automatically

Tags: windows-7, bios, operating-systems, ubuntu-11.10

I have installed both Ubuntu 11.10 and Windows 7. My system was working fine when suddenly I got the blue screen of death (bsod) while logging into windows 7. It said about the ACPI compliant and when I Googled, it said something about updating the bios and to contact my PC vendor. (in this case Zenith).

I did not want to login into windows, thus started to work on Ubuntu. After few days, when I started my system, it restarted automatically many a times before even reaching the section where I can chose between Ubuntu and Windows. Even before this happens, it just stays shut down for a while (i.e.) it keeps restarting for like 10 times and then suddenly the CPU light is on, but nothing is displayed as output on the monitor screen. When this happens, I had to force shut down by turning off the mains. Even pressing the restart button or the power didn't help. After a lot of tries am able to login either into Windows or Ubuntu.

The restart doesn't occur after I login, but say 2 days once, it restarts, while am working from an OS, especially happened in Ubuntu maybe because I was using only Ubuntu for a long time.

Could you please help me if you have encountered a similar problem or if you understand what the issue is?

**NOTE**: Recent update.

Thanks for reading this question and trying to solve it. Just within the seconds I finished this question here, my system CPU LITERALLY went boom, with a large sound and spark. Mostly an hardware issue which I don't know why again. Anyways, I hope people will take it as an symptom hereafter for a serious hardware issue and deal with it right away. If you know why this exactly happened, please help me. I can avoid it in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a problem with your motherboard or PSU. Low-end PSUs usually fail at stabilising voltages. Motherboard capacitors get killed after few years and PC starts to behave strangely. Starting problems are common, sometimes hardware fails mid-work as you've described.

I'm afraid it's too late now. I guess your PSU is dead, very likely motherboard will need replacement too. Hard drives may be damaged. It's possible that repair won't be worthwile.